# Zero operator on a dense domain

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a, possibly unbounded, self-adjoint operator with a dense domain $D(T)$ in a Hilbert space $H$. If $T=0$ on $D(T)$, can $T$ be different from the $0$ operator, i.e. $Tv=0$ for all $v\in H$?

Answer (score 2):

Any self adjoint operator is closed. It is obvious that if $A$ is bounded and closed then $D(A)=H.$

Answer (score 1):

The domain of the adjoint is the whole Hilbert space.

$$0=<Tx,y>=<x,T^*y>\ \ \forall x\in D(T),y\in H$$

Then we have $0=<x,T^*y>\ \ \forall x\in H$ as $D(T)$ is dense, so $T^*y=0\ \ \forall y\in H$.